# How to upload arduino code using xbee module ( pro s2c)?

Tags: arduino-mega, xbee

I have three arduino **ATMega2560** boards, all have **xbee pro s2c** attached to them. Now i want to update the code i had previously written on the arduino board but without connecting it to the computer. So basically I want to upload a code to arduino board via the xbee module I have attached to it, code is transmitted to this xbee from another xbee. Anyone with any type of ideas please share....

Comment: You could do it like I update the application in Mega in ArduinoOTA library https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA/blob/master/src/InternalStorageAVR.cpp it requires to changed the bootloader to Optiboot with `copy_flash_pages` function https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA#atmega-support

Comment: updated application binary is received to upper half of the flash memory with Optiboot's `do_spm` function and after then copied to the beginning of the flash with `copy_flash_pages` function of Optiboot. `copy_flash_pages` then resets the MCU.

Comment: thanks a lot @Juraj i will try that and let you know if this was helpful